# ASP.NET MVC3 bundles not getting cached on client

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, bundle

My bundles does not get cached on the client. Every request made it downloads the bundle everytime. What can be the cause of this? Also with fiddler I can see that the request to the bundle is "green" everytime.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the response header to check if the cache control is set.
If not you have to implement it